# Nestjs doesn't handle request from nginx proxy_pass using docker-compose

Tags: typescript, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm facing an issue using Nestjs with an request coming from proxy_pass by nginx with docker-compose.

I have a nestjs service that listen on the port 3000 with the following endpoints

- get /api/users/:id
- get /api/users
- post /api/users

I have the following nginx configuration

```
events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}
http {

    upstream ticketing_users {
        server ticketing_users:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ticketing.dev;

        location ~ ^/api/users(.*)$ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_pass http://ticketing_users/;
        }

        access_log /var/logs/nginx/access_log access;
        error_log  /var/logs/nginx/error.log error;
    }
}
```

Here is my nginx config in docker-compose.yaml :

```
reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx:/var/logs/nginx
    networks:
      - ticketing.dev
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - ticketing_users
    links:
      - ticketing_users
```

Here is my main.ts :

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(UsersModule, {
    cors: true,
    logger: ['verbose', 'debug', 'error', 'warn']
  });
  app.set('trust proxy', true);
  app.use(morgan('combined'));
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and my controller (generated with cli so it's declared in the module) :

```js
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  @Get(':id')
  public findById(@Param('id') id: string): string {
    return id;
  }
}
```

And i've set ticketing.dev in my host file.
But when i'm querying for exemple `get http://ticketing.dev:8080/api/users/1234` with postman i always get the same result, i tried to put some console.logs but nothing appears :

> {
> "statusCode": 404,
> "message": "Cannot GET /api/users/1234",
> "error": "Not Found" }

But morgan middleware handle correctly the request and is showing :

> GET /api/users/test 404 0.496 ms - 77

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_pass http://ticketing_users;`?

Comment: Yes but my service ticketing_users is listening on port 3000, actually i have created a new project from stratch and copy pasted all the code and it works on the new repo (maybe some cache somewhere) i've tried `docker-compose rm --all & docker-compose build --no-cache & docker-compose up --force-recreate` on the old one but nothing...